# how to prevent firefox always to start on the last space it was closed?

Tags: 18.04, firefox, workspaces

I do not know how, but after the last kernel update when I start Firefox it goes to another workspace. It is annoying for me, because sometimes there is just one workspace available on my screen, I'm trying to start the browser, I see the window for a very short time and it dissapears..So I search all workspaces and I see it open on another newly created for example 4th workspace... And I have 3 empty workspaces and the Firefox is on the 4th and when I switch to it all other workspaces dissappears. If there are like 5 workspaces available and I want to lunch it in the 4th for example, it starts the same way and I have to check out all the workspaces in order to find where it is... Anyone else experiencing the same problem? Is it possible to make it start **always on the current space** ?

---- EDIT:

I've noticed that it works this way if "Restore previous session" is enabled. Before the kernel update I just did this setting doesn't make Firefox to behave this way. I wish to keep my last opened tabs, but not to go on another empty workspace, is it possible?

`ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/
total 132
drwxr-xr-x 33 bo bo 4096 апр 25 23:54 .
drwx------  3 bo bo 4096 май 21 21:46 ..
drwxrwxr-x  4 bo bo 4096 юни 15  2019 activities-config@nls1729
drwxr-xr-x  3 bo bo 4096 сеп  8  2017 appmenu-regular-icons@example.com
drwxrwxr-x  2 bo bo 4096 юни 26  2019 auto_fullscreen@kibouo
drwxrwxr-x  2 bo bo 4096 юли 26  2019 autohide-battery@sitnik.ru
drwxrwxr-x  5 bo bo 4096 юни 14  2019 caffeine@patapon.info
drwxrwxr-x  4 bo bo 4096 юни 15  2019 CoverflowAltTab@palatis.blogspot.com
drwxrwxr-x  8 bo bo 4096 апр 25 23:52 cpupower@mko-sl.de
drwxrwxr-x  3 bo bo 4096 сеп 12  2017 customcorner@eccheng.gitlab.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 bo bo 4096 сеп  8  2017 disable-screenshield@lgpasquale.com
drwxrwxr-x  3 bo bo 4096 юни 15  2019 drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x  7 bo bo 4096 окт 30  2019 dynamic-panel-transparency@rockon999.github.io
drwxrwxr-x  3 bo bo 4096 юни 14  2019 fq@megh
drwxrwxr-x  2 bo bo 4096 юни 26  2019 fullscreenworkspace@satran.in
drwxrwxr-x  2 bo bo 4096 окт 30  2019 gnome-shell-extension-maximized-by-default@axe1.github.com
drwxrwxr-x  2 bo bo 4096 юни 26  2019 HideOverviewWhenClickOverview@love_li2@163.com
drwxrwxr-x  3 bo bo 4096 апр 25 23:54 impatience@gfxmonk.net
drwxrwxr-x  5 bo bo 4096 апр 25 18:19 lockkeys@vaina.lt
drwxrwxr-x  2 bo bo 4096 сеп 14  2017 maximize-to-workspace@rliang.github.com
drwxrwxr-x  4 bo bo 4096 ное 20  2019 middleclickclose@paolo.tranquilli.gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x  3 bo bo 4096 ное 20  2019 rcd@criztovyl.space
drwxrwxr-x  4 bo bo 4096 апр 25 18:18 set-columns@maestroschan.fr
drwxrwxr-x  4 bo bo 4096 дек 10 22:28 simplenetspeed@biji.extension
drwxrwxr-x  5 bo bo 4096 ное 18  2019 SystemMenu@jonnius.github.com
drwxrwxr-x  4 bo bo 4096 юни 15  2019 system-monitor@paradoxxx.zero.gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x  4 bo bo 4096 апр 25 18:22 text_translator@awamper.gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x  5 bo bo 4096 юни 14  2019 TopIcons@phocean.net
drwxrwxr-x  2 bo bo 4096 сеп 12  2017 transparentnotification@ipaq3870
drwxr-xr-x  2 bo bo 4096 сеп  8  2017 transparentosd@ipaq3870
drwxrwxr-x  3 bo bo 4096 юни 15  2019 user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x  4 bo bo 4096 юни 15  2019 windowoverlay-icons@sustmidown.centrum.cz
drwxrwxr-x  5 bo bo 4096 юни 15  2019 workspaces-to-dock@passingthru67.gmail.com`

`ls -ls /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 4

### 4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 фев 10  2019 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com`

`sudo grep -i stack /var/log/syslog*
[sudo] password for bo: 
/var/log/syslog:May 21 21:22:40 bo-ubu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[5655]: == Stack trace for context 0x55afdd094340 ==
/var/log/syslog:May 21 21:23:09 bo-ubu systemd[1]: Listening on Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
/var/log/syslog:May 21 21:23:09 bo-ubu systemd[1]: Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
/var/log/syslog:May 21 21:23:09 bo-ubu kernel: [    0.063551] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:on, heap free:off
/var/log/syslog:May 21 21:23:09 bo-ubu systemd[1]: Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
/var/log/syslog:May 21 21:24:31 bo-ubu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1743]: == Stack trace for context 0x55a7102fa340 ==
/var/log/syslog:May 21 21:24:31 bo-ubu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1743]: == Stack trace for context 0x55a7102fa340 ==
/var/log/syslog:May 21 21:39:56 bo-ubu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1743]: == Stack trace for context 0x55a7102fa340 ==
/var/log/syslog:May 21 21:39:56 bo-ubu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1743]: == Stack trace for context 0x55a7102fa340 ==
/var/log/syslog:May 21 21:39:56 bo-ubu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1743]: == Stack trace for context 0x55a7102fa340 ==
/var/log/syslog:May 21 21:39:56 bo-ubu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1743]: == Stack trace for context 0x55a7102fa340 ==
/var/log/syslog:May 21 21:39:56 bo-ubu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1743]: == Stack trace for context 0x55a7102fa340 ==
/var/log/syslog:May 21 21:39:56 bo-ubu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1743]: == Stack trace for context 0x55a7102fa340 ==
/var/log/syslog:May 21 21:39:56 bo-ubu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1743]: == Stack trace for context 0x55a7102fa340 ==
/var/log/syslog:May 21 21:39:56 bo-ubu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1743]: == Stack trace for context 0x55a7102fa340 ==
/var/log/syslog:May 21 21:40:09 bo-ubu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1743]: == Stack trace for context 0x55a7102fa340 ==
/var/log/syslog:May 21 21:40:09 bo-ubu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1743]: == Stack trace for context 0x55a7102fa340 ==
/var/log/syslog:May 21 21:40:09 bo-ubu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1743]: == Stack trace for context 0x55a7102fa340 ==
/var/log/syslog:May 21 21:40:09 bo-ubu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1743]: == Stack trace for context 0x55a7102fa340 ==
/var/log/syslog:May 21 21:40:09 bo-ubu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1743]: == Stack trace for context 0x55a7102fa340 ==
/var/log/syslog:May 21 21:40:09 bo-ubu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1743]: == Stack trace for context 0x55a7102fa340 ==
/var/log/syslog:May 21 21:40:09 bo-ubu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1743]: == Stack trace for context 0x55a7102fa340 ==
/var/log/syslog:May 21 21:50:04 bo-ubu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1743]: == Stack trace for context 0x55a7102fa340 ==
/var/log/syslog:May 21 21:50:04 bo-ubu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1743]: message repeated 3 times: [ == Stack trace for context 0x55a7102fa340 ==]
/var/log/syslog:May 21 21:50:04 bo-ubu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1743]: == Stack trace for context 0x55a7102fa340 ==
/var/log/syslog:May 21 21:50:24 bo-ubu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1743]: == Stack trace for context 0x55a7102fa340 ==
/var/log/syslog:May 21 21:50:24 bo-ubu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1743]: message repeated 3 times: [ == Stack trace for context 0x55a7102fa340 ==]
/var/log/syslog:May 21 21:50:24 bo-ubu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1743]: == Stack trace for context 0x55a7102fa340 ==
/var/log/syslog:May 21 21:52:04 bo-ubu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1743]: == Stack trace for context 0x55a7102fa340 ==
/var/log/syslog:May 21 21:52:04 bo-ubu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1743]: message repeated 3 times: [ == Stack trace for context 0x55a7102fa340 ==]
/var/log/syslog:May 21 21:52:04 bo-ubu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1743]: == Stack trace for context 0x55a7102fa340 ==
/var/log/syslog:May 21 21:52:14 bo-ubu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1743]: == Stack trace for context 0x55a7102fa340 ==
/var/log/syslog:May 21 21:52:14 bo-ubu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1743]: message repeated 4 times: [ == Stack trace for context 0x55a7102fa340 ==]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 21 21:16:10 bo-ubu systemd[1]: Listening on Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
/var/log/syslog.1:May 21 21:16:10 bo-ubu systemd[1]: Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
/var/log/syslog.1:May 21 21:16:10 bo-ubu kernel: [    0.063655] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:on, heap free:off
/var/log/syslog.1:May 21 21:16:10 bo-ubu systemd[1]: Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
/var/log/syslog.1:May 21 21:17:51 bo-ubu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[5655]: == Stack trace for context 0x55afdd094340 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 21 21:17:51 bo-ubu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[5655]: == Stack trace for context 0x55afdd094340 ==`

Comment: By spaces do you mean workspaces? Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -ls /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema yes, workspaces. Question edited with the outputs of the above commands

Comment: Holy !@#$% batman... you've got WAY TOO MANY GNOME Shell extensions installed, and at least one or two of them probably are responsible for moving app windows to specific workspaces. You need to disable all but 1-5 of the ones that you can't live without. I wouldn't be surprised if your syslog wasn't full of gnome-shell crashes. Do `grep -i stack /var/log/syslog*`. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema True, they are a lot, probably I have like 15 more which I have disabled because I can live without them) I'm a bit additcted to ux/ui so that's why I have so many, any of them has some purpose to be installed, but the main reason is to customize the ui the way I want it to be. I do not see anything unusual into the log above, I have to add sudo because otherwise I do not have access to the logs. I don't believe it is because of the extensions, because I have the same problem using ubuntu based elementaryOS with pantheon and no extensions at all. And it started after a kernel update.

Comment: **I'm correct. Your gnome-shell is crashing all over the place. See all of the "Stack trace" errors... caused by bad GNOME Shell extensions.** Also, did you find the one that moves app windows to specific workspaces? I don't really care about UI mods, but you've got to dump some GS extensions. Get it down to 1-5 extensions.

Comment: @heynnema these two that move the app window to a new space are disabled, but I will remove them at all. I will start to disable one by one all of them and check the logs, thanks for your time!

Comment: For a slightly more scientific way... review /var/log/syslog, look for "Stack trace" by gnome-shell, and many times it'll tell you exactly which GS extension caused it. Use an app called `glogg` to make this search really easy.